# Twig extension filter or function name in twig variable does not work?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

```
{{ row[col.key] | col.filter }}
```

I have filter in a col.filter variable. I tried creating eval filter like mentioned in following link, https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/pull/53/files and also tried https://github.com/marcj/twig-apply_filter-bundle or calling like

```
{{ row[col.key] | eval(col.filter) }}
```

or

```
{{ eval(row[col.key] , col.filter) }}
```

But it doesn't work.

Demo for the issue is here,

https://github.com/vishalmelmatti/twig_dynamic_filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a bit hairy, but how about using a [template_from_string](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html) + [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html) approach? Somewhat ugly, and probably quite expensive, but at least it should work.

#### Proof of concept:

```
{% set col, row = { key: 'x', filter: 'raw' }, { x: '<b>one</b>', y: '<b>two</b>' } %}
{{ include(template_from_string('{{ row[col.key]|' ~ col.filter ~ ' }}')) }}
```

...which will output: **one**

While this...

```
{% set col, row = { key: 'x', filter: 'escape' }, { x: '<b>one</b>', y: '<b>two</b>' } %}
...
```

...will output: <b>one</b>

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had almost given up, you saved !

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this at this point, but I suggest you to create your own twig method or filter that takes the filter you want to apply as an argument.

I suggest you to use or get inspiration from this bundle : https://github.com/marcj/twig-apply_filter-bundle

Comment: https://github.com/marcj/twig-apply_filter-bundle is created after discussing with me yesterday (check the authored time), tried it but its not working so trying to find some other solution,

Comment: can you please describe in more detail what 'But it doesn't work.' mean? No output, error, no filtering? the repo I've posted is unit-tested and should therefore work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the IRC, you could go for another approach, and use a `Format` interface to apply formating to your elements:

Here you have a simple POC https://gist.github.com/Lumbendil/d94109e91ceab7fae7e7

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

https://github.com/marcj/twig-apply_filter-bundle

It's a Symfony bundle that provides exactly what you need. You can use it without symfony as well.

Comment: Thanks, This link is alrealy mentioned in question.